# IsBasicLatin and IsLatin-1Supplement as JavaScript regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a two-step validity checks, the first one is in pure JavaScript and the second one, which is not maintained by me (I don't even know what language could be), is:

```
<xs:pattern value="[\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}]{1,1000}" />
```

For a better user experience, I need to be absolutely sure that the first step validates correctly so that the second one will never throw any other error.

I did a "standard" regular expression checking for letters, numbers and so on, but still there are some differences and the second one still finds someting invalid, sometimes.

This is my actual code:

```
var re = /^[\wáéíóäëiöúàèììù.,;:<>_ °!?#^$€£%\(\)\[\]\=\"\'|\\\/\-\+\*\&@]+$/gm;
return re.test(value);
```

Is there a way to use `IsBasicLatin` (and its supplement) in a JavaScript regular expression? Or how can I write a regex test that is exactly like those?

Comment: Saved on the edge of darkness. -1 to the dooms day

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your second step is an [XML Schema pattern](http://www.xmlschemareference.com/regularExpression.html#CharacterBlock) that supports Unicode category classes. The pattern `\p{IsBasicLatin}` stands for `[\x00-\x7F]` and `\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}` stands for `[\x80-\xFF]` (see [Unicode reference](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr44/)).

Also, XSD patterns are meant to match the entire input (they are ["anchored by default"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557392/what-is-the-difference-between-an-anchored-regex-and-an-un-anchored-regex)), so in JS you will have to enclose the pattern with `^` and `$`.

So, you can translate the xs:pattern regex into JS as

```
^[\x00-\xFF]{1,1000}$
```

Or

```
^[\u0000-\u00FF]{1,1000}$
```

Mind that the limiting quantifier is used in the xs:pattern regex to allow 1 to 1000 characters. Your first regex allows unlimited number of occurrences with `+` quantifier.

Comment: Thank you so much, this works perfectly. I am aware that I was not checking the string's length with my regex, but I have a separate test for that.