# What is the difference between an anchored regex and an un-anchored regex?

Tags: regex

What is the difference between an anchored regex and an un-anchored regex?

Usage [found here](https://buckbuild.com/rule/cxx_library.html):

> ... These should be specified as a list of pairs where the first element is an ***un-anchored regex*** (in `java.util.regex.Pattern` syntax) against which the platform name is matched...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*Unanchored regex* means a regex pattern that has no anchors, `^` for start of string, and `$` for the end of string, and thus allows *partial matches*. E.g. in Java, `Matcher#find()` method can search for partial matches inside an input string, `"a.c"` will find a match in `"1.0 abc."`. The anchored `"^a.c$"` pattern will match an `"abc"` string, but won't find a match in `"1.0 abc."`.

Also, an unanchored regex may mean the code that handles the regex pattern does not check if the match is equal to full input string. E.g. in Java, `Matcher#matches()` method requires that the pattern must match the full input string and `s.matches("a.c")` will match an `"abc"` string, but won't find a match in `"1.0 abc."`.

Anchored regex means the pattern will only match a string if the whole string matches.

See [Start of String and End of String Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) for more information about anchors in regex.

Comment: BTW, Scala examples may be more illustrative (see [Scala regex anchored example](https://www.garysieling.com/blog/scala-regex-anchored-example)). `"pattern".r.anchored` or `"pattern".r.unanchored` will behave differently with a `"A pattern"` string.