# Extract specific string using regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to extract only a specific string if its match

example as an input string:

- 13.10.0/
- 13.10.1/
- 13.10.2/
- 13.10.3/
- 13.10.4.2/
- 13.10.4.4/
- 13.10.4.5/

I'm using this regex `[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]` to extract only  digit.digit.digit from a string if its match
but in that case, this is the wrong output related to my regex :

13.10.0

13.10.1

13.10.2

13.10.3

13.10.4.2 (no need to match this string  13.10.4 )

13.10.4.4 (no need to match this string13.10.4 )

13.10.4.5(no need to match this string 13.10.4 )

the correct output that I need  :

- 13.10.0
- 13.10.1
- 13.10.2
- 13.10.3

Comment: `.` matches nearly any character. It does not match a literal `.`.

Comment: yes, use `[.]` or `\.` to match literal period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without knowing how you're passing these strings in -- are they lines in a file? An array of strings in a programming language?

If you're searching a file using `grep` or a similar tool, it will give you all lines that match *anywhere*, even if only part of the line matches.

Normally, you'd deal with this using [anchors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557392/what-is-the-difference-between-an-anchored-regex-and-an-un-anchored-regex) to specify the regex must start on the first character of the line, and end on the last (e.g. `^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]$`). `^` matches the start of the line, and `$` matches at the end.

In your case, you've got slashes at the end of all the lines, so the easiest fix is to match that final slash, with `^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]/`.

You could also use lookahead or groups to match the slash without returning it -- but that depends a bit more on what tool you're running this regex in and how you're processing it.

---

If your strings are separated by whitespace (other than newlines), replacing `^` with `(^|\s)` (either the beginning of the string, or some whitespace character) may work -- but it will add a leading space to some of your results.

You may also need to set your regex tool to match multiple times in a line (e.g. the `-o` flag in `grep`). Again, it's hard to give useful advice about this without knowing what regular-expression tool you're using, or how you're processing the results.

Comment: and if there is white space how can I handle it ? example `13.10.0/ 13.10.1/ 13.10.2/ 13.10.3/ 13.10.0.2/`

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+$
```

Which is exactly 3 groups of digit(s) separates by (literal) dots.

Answer (score 0):

Some tools (like grep) match all lines that contain your regex, and may have additional characters before/after.
Use `$` character to match end of line after your regex. (Also note, that `.` matches any character, not literal dot)

```
[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]$
```